# AWS CloudFormation template for CloudWatch alarm: how to describe the alarm with metrics by ElasticSearch node, not by whole ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, infrastructure-as-code

I have CloudFormation template for CloudWatch alarm which works with metrics from ElasticSearch cluster, here it is:

```
...
Resources:
  EsCPUUtilizationTooHighAlarm:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "es-cpu-utilization-too-high"
      AlarmActions:
      - !Ref AlarmsSnsTopic
      AlarmDescription: "ES cluster CPU usage above 80%"
      ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
      TreatMissingData: "missing"
      Dimensions:
      - Name: ClientId
        Value: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      - Name: DomainName
        Value: !Ref ElasticsearchCluster
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: "CPUUtilization"
      Namespace: "AWS/ES"
      Period: "300"
      Statistic: "Average"
      Threshold: "80"
...
```

This alarm tracks metrics from whole ElasticSearch cluster as you see, but I'd like to create few such alarms and track each ElasticSearch node separately. How can I describe such CloudWatch alarm with CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0):

The [Managing Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-instance-metrics) documentation lists metrics that are available for each individual instance in the cluster, mostly around Thread Pools and JVM metrics.

There is a `SysMemoryUtilization` metric defined as `The percentage of the instance's memory that is in use`.

Comment: I can see CPU Utilization metric for each separate ES node in CloudWatch Metrics panel (in web console).

Comment: Oops! Edited to include `SysMemoryUtilization`

Comment: But anyway I have a question - how to describe in CloudFormation template two CloudWatch alarms - one for master ES node and another for data ES node?

Comment: It's probably not possible to do via CloudFormation, because the stack does not know about the individual instances. You'd have to create the alarms outside of CloudFormation, such as writing a script to iterate through the nodes and create alarms.